# error while retrieving data from database on windows form application

Tags: database, winforms

trying to retrieve some data from the database and put in into my form. the code goes

```
notificationList.Add(new notificationForm(
            (String)dataset.Tables["alertdetails"].Rows[0]["memberName"],
            (String)dataset.Tables["alertdetails"].Rows[0]["locationName"],
            (String)dataset.Tables["alertdetails"].Rows[0]["photo"],
            "",
            (String)dataset.Tables["alertdetails"].Rows[0]["memberid"], 
            "",
            "", x, y, alertId));
```

the arguments for my notificationForm is

```
public notificationForm(String name, String location, String imageExtension,
                        String alertType,String memberid,String date,String time,
                        int x,int y,String alertid)
```

the error goes

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

on the line whereby i retrieve memberid. anyone know how to fix that? it works fine for memberName, locationName and photo though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataset.Tables["alertdetails"].Rows[0]["memberid"]
```

gives you the integer value, if the datatype of `memberid` in the database is int.
Then, either add `ToString()` at the end or cast it to an int.

Example:

```
dataset.Tables["alertdetails"].Rows[0]["memberid"].ToString()
                      OR
Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables["alertdetails"].Rows[0]["memberid"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to an `int` (32bit integer), which is what the error message is telling you.

Check the type of 'memberid' column in the database table. Presumably it is an integer.